# Confusion with increment operator?

Tags: java

(1)

```
 int z=0;
 int r=((z++)+z);
```

here i guess while computing the expression, the value of variable z is considered as 1.
but before ; how the variable z can be updated.

(2)

```
int y3=0;
int r3=y3=y3++;
System.out.print("(r3+y3)"+"\t"+r3+"\t"+y3);  



here how y3 is still 0 after evaluation of expression y3++, it should have increased by 1.
```

Answer (score 1):

Post increment `x++` is an expression that returns the value of x and only then increments x.

Hence:

```
int y0 = 0;    // y0 is 0
y0 = y0++;
```

Is the same as:

```
int y0 = 0;
int x = y0++;     // x = 0, y0=1
y0 = x;           // y0 again 0
```

Answer (score 1):

`variable++` returns the **original value** of `variable`. Example:

```
int variable = 0;
System.out.println(variable++); // 0
System.out.println(variable);   // 1
```

If you want the new value, use `++variable`:

```
int variable = 0;
System.out.println(++variable); // 1
System.out.println(variable);   // 1
```

So, here's a step-by-step breakdown of the first one:

1. `int z=0; // z is 0 now`
2. `int r=((z++)+z);`
3. `int r=(0+z); // z is 1 now`
4. `int r=(0+1);`
5. `int r=1;`

And the second:

1. `int y3=0; // y3 is 0 now`
2. `int r3=y3=y3++;`
3. `int r3=y3=0; // y3 was incremented to 1, but then we immediately set it back to 0`

Answer (score 1):

Just follow this rule: `x++` first increments `x` by `1` and then returns the *old* value .

### (1)

```
        int z = 0;
        int r = z++ + z;
Step1:      r = 0 + z; z = 1;
Step2:      r = 0 + 1;
Step3:      r = 1;
```

### (2)

```
        int y3 = 0;
        int r3 = y3 = y3++;
Step1:      y3 = 1; // New value by increment
Step2:      y3 = 0; // Old value
Step3:      r3 = y3;
```